# Best method of making it responsive

Tags: theming, advertising

We are using the Drupal Ad Module and require it to be responsive.

Used module: https://www.drupal.org/project/ad

One method I can think of would be to run Javascript to serve the same file name up but make the size of the screen control the dimensions of the file by selecting from the appropriate folder.

Anyone found a better way as this method relies on additional files being uploaded along side the one used in the ad module?

Is letting CSS resize it alone a viable option?